# system.log shows two lines DEBUG (7): 4 and DEBUG (7): 6 when home page is loaded

Tags: debug, system.log

I cant for the life of me figure this out.
these two lines get added to var/log/system.log 

`2015-09-23T07:32:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): 4
2015-09-23T07:32:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): 6`

every time home page is loaded. It only does it on home page and not catalog, product view or cms. Eventually the log becomes hundreds of megabytes if i dont watch it. I have disabled almost all of my 3rd party modules and cleared cache but still shoes up. Help please???

Comment: Try searching for Mage::log in your community and local code pools

Comment: If you want to get rid of the log at all go to:
System->Configuration->Developer Settings ( left menu at the bottom usually) and deactivate log. Otherwise as suggested by @Smartie search for `Mage::log(` or `->log(` just in case for an adjusted log function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into your templates for lines like: "Mage::log()"

This is the function that is used to write lines in the system.log file.

If you're using a module for your homepage, look into the module as well.

First thing I would do is switch the theme to default/default and try to reload your homepage.

If lines are not added with the theme default/default that means the "Mage::log()" lines are in the template files of your custom theme.

In the other case, they are either in the fallback theme folders (base/default and your_package/default) or in the app/code/local and app/code/community folder.

You can use the following command on your app/design/frontend/, app/code/local and app/code/community folder to look for the specific line:

```
grep -r "Mage::log(" .
```